# Share data between different ViewModels using a Shared ViewModel in Android

Tags: android, mvvm

I have multiple fragments which each has a distinct `ViewModel`. Now I want to avoid passing data as an argument between my `Fragments` and instead use a `SharedViewModel` between my `Viewmodels` and somehow to inherit the `Sharedviewmodel` to update my data states. Any help?

Comment: I have heard a fragment can have a sharedviewmodel and a private viewmodel and that is provided by Viewmodel Provider.. I am just not sure how to implement that

Answer (score 0):

ViewModel inheritance is probably the wrong tool to use for that, since the ViewModel is designed to be tied to the lifecycle of a specific Fragment or Activity. A better approach would be to have a true "Model" class that manages persistent data state (singleton or otherwise) that the individual ViewModels interface with. For example:

```
class Database {

    private static Database instance = null;

    public static synchronized Database getInstance() {
        if( instance == null ) {
            instance = new Database();
        }
        return instance;
    }

    private Database() {}

    private int mValue = 0;
    public void setValue(int v) { mValue = v; }
    public int getValue() { return mValue; }
}


class FragmentAViewModel extends ViewModel {

    private final Database db;

    FragmentAViewModel() {
        db = Database.getInstance();
    }

    // FragmentA can set and get state on Database as needed
    void setValue(int v) {
        db.setValue(v);
    }
}

class FragmentBViewModel extends ViewModel {

    private final Database db;

    FragmentBViewModel() {
        db = Database.getInstance();
    }

    // FragmentB can set and get state on Database as needed
    int getValue() {
        return db.getValue();
    }
}
```

Another option would be to create an Activity-level ViewModel. If all the Fragments are within the same activity they can share that Activity ViewModel. For example:

```
mFragmentViewModel = ViewModelProviders.of(this).get(FragmentViewModel.class);

MainActivity a = (MainActivity)requireActivity();
mActivityViewModel = ViewModelProviders.of(a).get(MainActivityViewModel.class);
```

Comment: I am trying to avoid using Repositories

Comment: If you are trying to create a class that outlives the lifecycle of a given fragment or activity then this is what you are describing. A ViewModel is a lifecycle-aware component.

Comment: To understand in detail:
https://medium.com/@khadijahameed415/sharedviewmodel-in-kotlin-ec9b09b41a78